# What are advantages and disadvantages of different animation mechanisms

Tags: android, animation

So I see there are three animation mechanisms in Android:

1) [android.view.animation.Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html)

2) [android.animation.Animator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html)

3) [View.animate()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#animate%28%29)

What are differences between those three? How should I decide which to use? What are benefits of using each of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html). In short, there are three types of animations...

1. View Animations

   - Simple tween animations.
   - Can only modify position, size, rotation, and transparency.
   - Limited to View objects.
2. Property Animations

   - Can animate any property of a View (not limited to size, rotation, position, and transparency).
   - Not limited to just View objects.
3. Drawable Animations

   - Animate a set of drawables in sequence.
   - Similar to sprites.

What you decide to use, is totally up to you and dependent on what you're trying to achieve.  With this information in mind, use your best judgement.

***EDIT***

To clarify on your specific examples...

1. `Animation` is a base class for other Animation types like `AlphaAnimation`. It provides you the necessary methods to create your own `Animation` if you wish. This class has existed since API 1.
2. `Animator` is part of a newer set of animation tools. `ObjectAnimator` is an example implementation of `Animator`. I can't say much about it since I did not write it, but `Animator` and `Animation` seem to be very similar in that they both provide a way to create animations.
3. `ViewPropertyAnimator` is also part of the new animation tools providing an even easier way to animate View objects. It's also optimized to handle multiple animations.

For simple animations, View Animations are just fine. For more complex animations, Property Animations would be the way to go.

Comment: I've read this article before I posted this question. This doesn't describe difference between View.animate() and the others. Also, it doesn't really give suggestion what I should use on a `View`. All those options are viable.

Comment: @gruszczy View.animate() returns a `ViewPropertyAnimator`, which is very similar to `ObjectAnimator` in that they both are Property Animators, but `ViewPropertyAnimator` is optimized for animating multiple properties at once so it's a bit more efficient on that front. Also the syntax is much nicer.

Comment: `ViewPropertyAnimator` doesn't extend `ObjectAnimator`, how similar are they then?

Comment: @gruszczy I meant that in their behavior is similar.

Comment: @gruszczy I've updated my answer to hopefully clarify any confusions.